# How can I hide a togglable p:panel before the page loads?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, panel, conditional-rendering

I have a JSF page with 2 components, a button and panel. The button calls jQuery `toggle` to hide and show the panel. I would like that when the page loads, the panel is initially hidden, so that when I press the button  for the first time, the panel shows up.

```
<p:commandButton onclick="PF('panelMatches').toggle()" value="Matches" type="button" />
<p:panel id="button_panel" widgetVar="panelMatches" closable="true" toggleable="true">
    Matches: 0
</p:panel>
```

With this code the panel is always initially visible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just use `collapsed="true"` as an attribute on `<p:panel>`. Then it will be rendered "closed" from the beginning and the first call to `toggle()` will open it.

Refer to the documentation of the primefaces version you are using: http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html

```
Name      | Default | Type    | Description
collapsed | false   | Boolean | Renders a toggleable panel as collapsed.
```